# Is Firebase + Batch a good alternative to Parse in terms of push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase

Parse was obviously the best back end for push notifications but since that'll be no more soon I'm looking for a good free alternative for an iOS app. After some research it seems using the Batch API with Firebase would be a good one. I just want to send pictures/video and text to a certain user.

If this is not possible or free does anyone have any other recommendations? Anything I should know?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Batch is very good alternative to Parse Push (disclosure: I'm a co-founder) but the product is not free for obvious reasons. I'll give you one: you don't want to migrate your push notifications every year because the free service you were using is closing.

You can also build the whole push notifications stack yourself by using Google Cloud Messaging but it can be painful and I guess you want to focus on your core business. The closest analogy is email, do you want to setup your own SMTP server? Probably not.

If you are also looking for a database like Parse Core, Firebase is a good candidate [and can be easily plugged to Batch if needed](https://batch.com/parse-replacement-with-firebase). But from what I know, they don't provide a static file upload method like you had with Parse. So you might have to use Amazon S3 or something like that (and store the files URLs in Firebase).